# Spring boot doesn't find JpaRepositories in sibling-package when using @ComponentScan or can't initialize them when using @EnableJpaRepositories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a maven project consisting of multiple modules. Three of these modules are

- "project-core" (Contains the model classes)
- "project-data" (Contains Spring Data JPA Repositories)
- "project-spring" (Contains the main Spring Boot App with REST controllers).

On startup I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.foo.bar.data.OrderRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I know that Spring Boot Applications by default only look in their own and their child packages for beans, but in this case the bean is in a sibling package. I already tried adding a `@ComponentScan({"org.foo.bar.data"})` to the Application class, but to no avail.

Using `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.foo.bar.data"})` throws

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class org.foo.bar.core.model.Order
```

What am I doing wrong?

The directory tree (trimmed) looks like this:

```
project
├── project-core
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── org
│                   └── foo
│                       └── bar
│                           └── core
|                               └── model
|                                   └── Order.java
├── project-data
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── org
│                   └── foo
│                       └── bar
│                           └── data
|                               └── OrderRepository.java
│
└── project-spring
    └── src
        └── main
            └── java
                └── org
                    └── foo
                        └── bar
                            └── spring
                                └── Application.java
```

OrderRepository:

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Integer> {
    List<Order> findByDeliveryOverview(DeliveryOverview deliveryOverview);
    List<Order> findByDeliveryOverviewAndCustomer(DeliveryOverview deliveryOverview, Customer customer);
}
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"org.foo.bar.data"})
public class Application {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is you are technically separating things instead of functional. Remove the component scan and add `@EntityScan` for the data package and also add `@EnableJpaRepositories` as you had before. Or simply move your `Application` class to `org.foo.bar` which is recommended.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The main problem is your structure.

To scan the entities you need an `@EntityScan` on your application class and to enable the repositories you need `@EnableJpaRepositories`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan({"org.foo.bar.core.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"org.foo.bar.data"})
public class Application { ... }
```

However I would suggest moving the `Application` class to `org.foo.bar` and then you only need the `@SpringBootApplication` as it will start scanning from that directory.

Comment: Thanks for posting this as an answer in addition to the comment. I settled on moving the Application class.

Answer (score 0):

annotate `OrderRepository` with `@Repository` and delete this statement `{"org.foo.bar.data"}` in `@ComponentScan`