# org.sf.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type X available

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, repository, component-scan

I'm trying to setup a simple project with a user repository in Spring Boot with Hibernate as JPA, I tried [this](http://zetcode.com/springboot/repository/) and [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) tutorials and in both (and everywhere) `@SpringBootApplication` seems to be sufficient to make the repository reachable throughout the app's scope since it includes `@ComponentScan`, except, in my case, it is not. Even [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35916625/4770813) looks tailored to my situation, but no.

**Project structure**

```
project
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── medisam
|                    └── Application.java
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── medisam
│                   └── entity
│                       └── User.java
|                       └── UserRepository.java
│    └── src
│        └── main
│            └── java
│               └── medisam
│                   └── controller
│                       └── MainController.java
```

With such structure and this code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    ...
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    ...
}
```

I get:

*...Error creating bean with name* ***'application'*** *: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repo'; nested exception is* ***org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException*** *: No qualifying bean of type* ***'medisam.entity.UserRepository'*** *available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as* ***autowire*** *candidate. Dependency annotations:* 
***{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}*** *...*

It is only when I do this:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"medisam.controller", "medisam.entity"})
@EntityScan({"medisam.entity"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"medisam.entity"})
public class Application {
    ...
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
    ...
}
```

that I get a working code but, if there is really a way of achieving this with only `@SpringBootApplication`, I'd like to use it.

Could it be that `@SpringBootApplication` is not scanning correctly?

Help please

**EDIT**

**UserRepository.java**

```
package medisam.entity;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

**User.java**

```
package medisam.entity;

import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Access;
import javax.persistence.AccessType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Role.class)
    @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SpringBootApplication will auto scan your entities/repo if they are under root or under its root packages if they are outside of your main class then you need to use auto scan to packages for Jpa repositories

Comment: @kj007, given the structure in the question, are my entities properly located in order for `@SpringBootApplication` to scan them properly?

Comment: No, your entity package should be under project-> project-main->src->main-java->medisam and auto configuration will work

Comment: @kj007, my bad but maybe the structure I posted is a little misleading: `project-main`, `project-entities` and `project-controllers` do not exist, they are just there to logically separate the classes, they are not folders in my project, try to see the tree without them, `src` is directly inside `project`. Sorry, I updated the question to reflect the actual structure

Comment: your structure seems to fine and should auto configure entities/repository and controllers, can you please just annotate UserRepository with @Repository and also please clean your project by running mvn clean install. if still not work would you mind to share your code on github, I can look at..please also show UserRepository class.

Comment: @kj007, I just added **User.java** and **UserRepository.java**. I'm not using Maven, but Gradle. I already *cleaned* and *built* my project in NetBeans. Should I do anything else in Gradle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181648/discussion-between-kj007-and-scaramouche).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed your code on gihub and found you have imported wrong package name in class `Application.java` and `ServiceResponse.java`.

Please import main package as `package medisam;` instead of `package hello;`.

like below:

**Your Application class:**

```
package medisam;
import medisam.entity.UserRepository;
import nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect;
import nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.decorators.strategies.GroupingStrategy;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Description;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.java8time.dialect.Java8TimeDialect;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ITemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.UrlTemplateResolver;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
```

**and here is your ServiceResponse**

```
package medisam;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.apache.catalina.util.ResourceSet;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ServiceResponse {
```